# component-wise convergence in $l^{2}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

let us consider the $x_{n} \in l^{2}$, for $n=1, 2, \dots$ and assume that $x_{n}^{(i)} \to x^{(i)}$, where subscript means the $i$-th component of $x_{n}$, and $x = (x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}, \dots) \in l^{2}$.

Is it true that $x_{n} \to x$?

I am thinking of using the Weierstrass M-test...

Comment: what you are describing here is called weak convergence, the topology induced is coarser.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "does $x_n$ converge to $x$ in $l_2$-norm?" the answer is no.
Take $x_n=e_n$, the vector with $1$ in the $n$-th component and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Or $x_n=ne_n ,$ to show that the sequence $(x_n)_n$ can converge weakly to $0$ and be unbounded in norm......+1

Comment: @DanielWainfleet weakly convergent sequence is (norm) bounded.